# Capture Olympus 5800PR US pulser/receiver data on my laptop

Tags: ultrasound, adc

Im tryng to place some ultrasound experiments at school and i have this pulser available ([Olympus 5800PR](http://www.olympus-ims.com/en/5800pr/)), the problem is that i dont know how to capture the data on my laptop. I know i have to set an adc to do this but maybe there are easier ways to do this, preferable the cheapest ones.

Hearing suggestions.. tnxs.

Oz!

Comment: Do you really need to record the ultrasound waves?  Or do you need to record the times and amplitudes of reflected pulses?  That thing apparently makes pulses at 35 MHz, which you're going to have a hard time recording...

Comment: Yep, i shouldve specified i want to get the reflected pulse´s information.. ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is a 0-1V output signal if my quick glance at the specs is right. If so, you can use a ADC to snag the values and then record them on your machine. You'll need to get something with a fast enough sample rate to get a clean signal. Have you looked at the output with a 'scope to see if the values match your expectations?

Answer (score -1):

I've done this in the past.
You need a fast acquisition device, minimum 100 Msamples/sec.
Nowadays there are many in the market at not so high prices.
(example: http://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope.html).

By the way, do you still have the 5800PR?

Comment: Whats your reasoning behind the number 100Msamples/sec?  OP gives no numbers and your answer doesn't quite answer the question.
Also since this question is from four years ago, "answering" it brings it to the top of the feed which works against current question getting more exposure.  Please refrain from this in the future unless the question has received absolutely no attention.